# Trying to take a div to footer of last page when printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I am trying hard to show a div in the last pages footer section.
But this not working for me. I have tried so many solutions given in
StackOverflow. But none of them are working for me.
Problem link is given below.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/minhajhasan/qzd8w14b/

I have tried with these codes to take my div in the footer.

```
<Style>
.print-address{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            height: 50px;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Do you want to display your footer on every page when it's printed right ?

Comment: @RémyTesta Nope, I just want to show the footer to the last page.

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 and CSS3 have no support for printing page header and footers in print media.

And while you might be able to simulate it with:

- tables fixed
- position blocks

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please show me in this fiddle how to use your idea. https://jsfiddle.net/minhajhasan/qzd8w14b/